# create method for object Store

Tags: php, python, oop

Create an object that represents a store. Have the initialization method take the square footage of the store. Create a method that can calculate the electrical costs for the store

```
class Store:
    DOLLARS_PER_KWH = 0.15
    KWH_PER_SQUARE_FOOTAGE_PER_HOUR = 0.19

    def __init__(self): 
        self.square_footage = square_footage

    def cost(self, DOLLARS_PER_KWH, KWH_PER_SQUARE_FOOTAGE_PER_HOUR):
        self.electrical_costs = self * DOLLARS_PER_KWH * KWH_PER_SQUARE_FOOTAGE_PER_HOUR
        print(f' Electrical costs are {self.electrical_costs} dollars.')
```

I receive a type error in the init call, and a name error with cost, what is the problem here? Please help edit my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 class Store:
        DOLLARS_PER_KWH = 0.15
        KWH_PER_SQUARE_FOOTAGE_PER_HOUR = 0.19

        def __init__(self,square_footage): 
            self.square_footage = square_footage
            Store.DOLLARS_PER_KWH
            Store.KWH_PER_SQUARE_FOOTAGE_PER_HOUR

        def cost(self):
            self.electrical_costs = self.square_footage *Store.DOLLARS_PER_KWH *Store.KWH_PER_SQUARE_FOOTAGE_PER_HOUR
            print ("Electrical costs are $%.2f." % (self.electrical_costs))

    emp1 = Store(10)       
    emp1.cost()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[A few pointers](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/pointers.png):

1. `square_footage` is not defined inside `__init__`, you probably meant to send it as a parameter
2. Sending `DOLLARS_PER_KWH` and `KWH_PER_SQUARE_FOOTAGE_PER_HOUR` to `cost` as parameters is most likely not what you wanted since they are already defined in the class.
3. `self *` part is wrong. You are not overloading `*`, thus you cannot multiply `Store` objects  with something else